# Set all channels to save revisions

Tags: multi-site-manager

How do you set all channels to have revisions? Especially on a big MSM site, this takes a lifetime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple SQL command will find all channels that doesn't have versioning enabled and will enable it remembering 10 revisions (change as you see fit).

```
UPDATE exp_channels
SET 'enable_versioning'='y', 'max_revisions'='10'
WHERE 'enable_versioning'='n'
```